# Setting onclick function dynamically in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, mouseevent

hello =)  I am trying to create a heading tag with some text in it.

```
var d = document.createElement("h5");
d.innerHTML = "Dungeon";
```

and then assigning an onclick listener.

```
d.onclick = function(){myFunction()};
```

which doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried

```
d.onmousedown = function(){myFunction();};
```

and

```
d.onclick = "myFunction()";
```

and

```
d.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){myFunction});
```

and none of them seem to be working.  I have thrown in a couple tracers around it, everything runs through fine without syntax errors but the actual element when appended to the document doesn't have the function tied to it at all.  Would anyone happen to know why?  Thanks in advance =)

Edit:
Here is a more detailed block of my code.  Would this make any difference?

```
var x = document.createElement("ul");
var y = document.createElement("li");
x.appendChild(y);
var d = document.createElement("h5");
d.innerHTML = "Dungeon";
y.appendChild(d);
console.log(0);
d.onclick = function() { alert('test'); }
console.log(1);
```

Comment: Have you `appended` `d` element in `DOM` ?

Comment: Yes i append it and it becomes visible.  Stated in the final sentences of my question =)

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 can you provide a JSFiddle which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 — Here is the working code(Without making any changes to your code!) https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/1tjey0g5/

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle, however I couldn't unfortunately.  @Rayon thank you for the provided example.  I created my own as well which also worked.  I replicated my code and just put a `document.body.appendChild(x)` at the end and it worked.  Must be an underlying problem in my actual code that I need to search for.

Comment: @DAXaholic — I was not sure about it hence I cleared my doubt my asking it in comment, I did not post the answer..

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by just saying `y.innerHTML += "<h5 onclick = 'myFunction()'>Dungeon</h5>`  Not sure why it didn't work dynamically.  I will have to look into it at a later time.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem.addEventListener("click", function, false);
```

Comment: Wow! How come this make any difference ?

Comment: This still didn't solve my problem but marked as correct.  I think it is too specific to get help on.

Comment: dude, can u copy your code to snippet, so that it is easy to understand n solve